# Spark job not running when jar is in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-submit

I am trying to run a spark job in standalone mode but the command is not picking up the jar from HDFS.The jar is present in the HDFS location and Its working fine when I run it in local mode.

Below is the command I am using

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn --class com.main.WordCount /spark/wc.jar
```

Below is my program:

```
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("yarn")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val file  = spark.textFile(args(0))

    val count = file.flatMap(f=>f.split(" ")).map(word=>(word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect
    count.foreach(println)
```

And I am getting below error:

```
Warning: Local jar /spark/wc.jar does not exist, skipping.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.main.WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

But If i use deploy mode cluster I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/spark/wc.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$Client$$distribute$1(Client.scala:433)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$10.apply(Client.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$10.apply(Client.scala:529)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:529)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1178)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Looking at the statement vs question, I am not convinced you are trying to run in standalone mode. Please clarify.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please clarify what is local mode. There are only two deploy mode client and cluster, the only difference is in client mode Driver program will run on the system and in cluster mode driver program will run from random node in the cluster.

For spark submit command:

When you execute spark submit command spark will pull all the local resources/files defined with --files , --py-files argument as well as Spark Main Jar to temporary HDFS location/directory, which is created by that particular spark application with the application name. when you give HDFS location, it will fail to location the Jar on local machine. It is mandatory to keep the Jar on local.

Comment: Please mark it as correct if you find this explanation correct.

Comment: This is the explanation I am looking from last two days, Thank you very much, My program is working now.

Comment: @KumarHarsh  update your question as it is badly formulated. pls include the correct command as part of the answer for others, not me